# Getting Abnormally high download speeds

Tags: windows, internet-speed

I finished using FUP of my broadband connection(25GB 2MBps and 512KBps after that).
so technically i should be getting 512/8 = max 64kbps for download, right?

[image]

here, iam getting 130s, 140s. but sometimes, i even get 500-800kbps. how is it possible?

is it some mistake done by my ISP ? 'cause am sure i havent changed the plan and speedtest results also tells me that currently my speed are 512kBps.

How is this possible?

**EDIT 1:** shortly, after writing this post, i got higher speeds

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

[image]

Comment: Some times there may be a bug from ISP side. Check with your ISP provider for your current plan and conform that you are in same plan what you have opted.

Comment: Shhhh! Don't tell your ISP, they'll be sure to throttle you!

Comment: Vembutech, my current plan remains the same!  and yeah, FreeMan, lol, am not gonna tell them!